# How to use Telethon with Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, telegram, telethon

I'm new with python and i want to se a google cloud function with [Telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/) but i can't do it because i have errors when running.

Here is Gcloud function code my code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
#from telethon import functions, types
#from telethon.tl.functions.channels import CreateChannelRequest, CheckUsernameRequest, UpdateUsernameRequest, InviteToChannelRequest
#from telethon.tl.types import InputChannel, InputPeerChannel

api_id = XXX
api_hash = 'XXX'

def hello_world(request):
    with TelegramClient("session_name", api_id, api_hash) as client:
        from telethon.tl.functions.channels import CreateChannelRequest, CheckUsernameRequest, UpdateUsernameRequest
        from telethon.tl.types import InputChannel, InputPeerChannel
        from telethon.tl.types import InputPhoneContact
        from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerUser
        from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ImportContactsRequest

        contact = InputPhoneContact(client_id=11111, phone='1111111111', first_name="Twilo Test",last_name="Phone")

        newcontact = client(ImportContactsRequest(contacts=[contact]))

        return newcontact.__dict__;
```

My requeriments.txt:

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
telethon
```

And i get the following error when i run the function (hello_world):

[image: python google cloud error on running]

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the issue, but I didn't get any error. If you look at the error, it says sqlite3.DatabaseError, but you have nowhere mentioned about the database and how you are using it, please edit your question to show the usage of the database in your code.

Comment: Hi @ZeenathSN thanks for your answer. This is all my code inside in a Google Cloud Function. Did you use å google cloud function?

Maybe Telethon uses a Database!

In my case locally the code works perfect.

Comment: yes, I did it in cloud functions. Can you try creating the function again referring this document:  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/first-python and tell us in which step you are getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Name and location of your Database is the `session_name`.
On Google Cloud functions only `/tmp` is writeable.

It has to look like this:

```
with TelegramClient("/tmp/session_name", api_id, api_hash) as client:
```